# No module named 'jqmcvi'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using **Jupyter Notebook** and I'm a very beginner. I'm stuck with the jqmcvi module I use for the Dunn index in clustering.
I've already tried installations like **!pip install jqmcvi** which doesn't work.

Can you help me and tell me what I need to do/install to use the jqmcvi module please?
Thank you in advance.